# C - Stack Implementation - malloc issue

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, declaration, definition

I'm trying to implement a brackets balance checker with stack, and I can't seem to shake off this

**Error**

```
tempCodeRunnerFile.c: In function ‘main’:
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:26:20: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct StackRecord’
   26 |  S = malloc(sizeof(*S));
      |
```

Here's the code:

**balance.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stack.h"

void main() 
{
    struct StackRecord *S;
    char str[500], c;
    int l, i;

    S = malloc(sizeof(*S));
    while (1) {
        .............
        .............
    
    return;
}
```

**stack.c**

```
        #include "stack.h"
        #include "fatal.h"
        #include <stdlib.h>

        #define EmptyTOS ( -1 )
        #define MinStackSize ( 5 )

        struct StackRecord
        {
            int Capacity;
            int TopOfStack;
            ElementType *Array;
        };

.............
.............
```

**stack.h**

```
typedef int ElementType;
/* START: fig3_45.txt */
        #ifndef _Stack_h
        #define _Stack_h

        struct StackRecord;
        typedef struct StackRecord *Stack;

        int IsEmpty( Stack S );
        int IsFull( Stack S );
        Stack CreateStack( int MaxElements );
        void DisposeStack( Stack S );
        void MakeEmpty( Stack S );
        void Push( ElementType X, Stack S );
        ElementType Top( Stack S );
        void Pop( Stack S );
        ElementType TopAndPop( Stack S );

        #endif  /* _Stack_h */

/* END */
```

I only put the *important* parts that cause the issue. It makes no sense since everything seems correct:/

Comment: If you want to create an opaque data structure, then you need to implement your own factory function for the creation of instances of the data structure.

Comment: You should read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). If you use GCC, compile with all warnings and debug info, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. You could want to have some [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)

Comment: You might want to read some C standard, e.g. [n2176](https://files.lhmouse.com/standards/ISO%20C%20N2176.pdf). You surely want to take inspiration from *existing* open source software, for example [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) or [GTK](https://gtk.org/). You could be interested by [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/)

Answer (score 2):

In the translation unit with main

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stack.h"

void main() 
{
    struct StackRecord *S;
    char str[500], c;
    int l, i;

    S = malloc(sizeof(*S));
    while (1) {
        .............
        .............
    
    return;
}
```

the definition of the structure `struct StackRecord`  is unknown. So the compiler is unable to calculate the size of an object of this type in the operator `sizeof`

```
S = malloc(sizeof(*S));
```

You need to move the structure definition from `"stack.c"` in the header `"stack.h"`.

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

instead of

```
void main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to allocate a `struct StackRecord`, one needs to know the size of a `struct StackRecord`. And to know the size of a `struct StackRecord` using the `sizeof` operator, one needs the definition of a `struct StackRecord`.

The problem is that the definition of `struct StackRecord` is not found anywhere in the current translation unit. (`stack.c` is not involved in compiling `balance.c`.)

To solve this problem, move the definition of `struct StackRecord` from `stack.c` to `stack.h`, or have `stack.c` provide a function to allocate a `struct StackRecord`.

Comment: But shouldn't compiling like this: `gcc balance.c stack.c` fix the problem?

Comment: That's short for `gcc -c balance.c; gcc -c stack.c; gcc balance.o stack.o` It compiles balance.c, then compiles stack.c, then links the two .o files. The size is needed during compilation, not linking.

Comment: @DaviHlav You need to learn about the concept of [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). The compiler doesn't see all source files, all it ever sees is a single translation unit (basically a single source file with all included header files). The compiler don't know anything about other translation units or what they contain. Even a command like `gcc balance.c stack.c` will build the two source files separately one by one.

Comment: @DaviHlav The code is not valid C, how you compile it doesn't change that.